# Matrix inversion, multiplication and eigen computation in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, matrix, linear-algebra, mahout

I need to perform these three steps:
- Find the inverse of a square symmetric matrix
- Multiply the result with another square symmetric matrix
- Finally, find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the resultant matrix

The python code:

```
S_i = np.linalg.inv(S1)
S_m = S_i*S2
evector, evalue = np.linalg.eig(S_m)
```

Is there an existing implementation of these steps in the Hadoop Map-Reduce framework?

I know about the SVD implementation in Mahout, and the inverse of a matrix can be computed using SVD *provided* there's an efficient multiplication implementation in Hadoop. Further, I could not find any eigenvector computation implementation for Hadoop.

Any suggestion/pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To fit Eigen vector computation into MapReduce you might want to take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm

Also this answer here [how to implement eigenvalue calculation with MapReduce/Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388302/how-to-implement-eigenvalue-calculation-with-mapreduce-hadoop)
details how

> PageRank solves the dominant eigenvector problem by iteratively
>   finding the steady-state discrete flow condition of the network.